# Genuinity of replays

Tags: cricket, video-review

How it is ensured that the replay shown for a particular incident is correct? For instance, while checking front foot no-ball, host broadcaster can edit and alter the footage to benefit the home team. Is match referee responsible for checking the correctness of the replays?

Comment: So you're basically asking how we know that nobody is faking the feed to cheat? Obviously, we can't, but I doubt the ICC is so stupid that they don't do anything about it.

Comment: @Nij ..Not just we.i dont think that any of the ICC match official even know about the genuineness of the replays shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The host broadcaster is trusted with that responsiblity.

There have been instances of errors in replays, such as [this case recently](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/1143649.html), but there's no evidence of cheating - it would involve collusion between teams, broadcasters and boards. Frankly, there's too much money involved for all of them to start that sort of messing.